# Blazor - Error when accessing to a published website with mobile device

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I create a blazor web assembly with visual studio template, with "Asp.net core hosted" option and "Progressive web app" option too.

All works fine in "localhost" and in the publish website (develop environment) when i visit my website with a computer.

But when i visit the same website with mobile devices, i have this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

I change the hosting model of asp.net core to "Out of Process", but i had the same result, only the message has changed.

```
HTTP Error 502.50 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Start Failure
```

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - don't know if you were using Identity but I was and the following fixed the issue:

- Ensure you have a folder with write permissions in the published root folder called **"obj"**. I think Identity creates a token key in here.
- Also ensure you have the Identity key set up in appsettings.cs as follows (probably shouldn't use development in production though):

> "IdentityServer": {
> "Key": {
> "Type": "Development"
> }
> }